# Broken ubuntu after sudo apt dist-upgrade?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, sudo

I was trying to install PHP on my Ubuntu and did a sudo apt dist-upgrade without seeing what was gonna be changed. After that I suddenly couldn't access settings, files or connect to internet they just gone from my menu so I restarted my machine thinking that would get back normal after that. Now my ubuntu is like this, a black screen with a terminal and I don't know how to get back to normal. Can someone help me please? [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnN6i.jpg)

edit 1: edited with more details about my problem

Edit 2: log history

[image: log]

Edit 3:

```
sudo apt list | grep gdm3
gdm3/focal-updates,now 3.36.3- 0ubuntu0.20.04.4 amd64 [residual-configuration]
```

Ctrl+alt+f2
[image: screen]

Comment: Why did you try to restart gdm? Please explain what your actual problem is, instead of just saying "it's like this" and including a screenshot. We don't know what you expected to happen.

Comment: I thought that restarting gdm would solve because when I restart my machine I only get that black screen to login. Sorry if I didn't explain that command

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to get my computer back to normal since now I only have this black screen with a terminal

Comment: You expected to get a graphical login screen? Please edit your question to explain what the issue is, and say what version of Ubuntu you are using. (I see it's 20.04, but many people won't look at the screen shot). Think about what the words you have written in the question say to someone who drops in and reads it. Right now, they don't say one single thing about the problem you are having - just that you are having a problem. Help us help you!

Comment: Yes. When I did sudo apt distro-update I suddenly couldn't get to settings or access internet so I restarted my machine but now I only get to that black screen with a terminal

Comment: Sorry @OrganicMarble, just edited and added more details about what I did and what I'm facing. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You may have uninstalled gdm, you can type this command in your tty: `sudo apt list | grep gdm3` to find for gdm package. If it is not there type:  `sudo apt install gdm3` but you may not have an internet connection with wifi... If you don't have wifi try by ethernet or with a phone you can share your connection with an usb cable plugged in your computer.

Comment: I think what you intended was `sudo apt dist-upgrade` rather than `sudo apt distro-upgrade`.  I don't know what the latter command does...

Comment: Sorry, it was sudo apt dist-upgrade. Typing mistake @mook765

Comment: You should use a "terminal text editor" like `vim` or `nano` and give us the last command that you use with apt; for example: `vim /var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: Edited with the history.log last 3 commands used

Comment: It's seems like nothing important was removed. what is the result `sudo apt list --installed | grep gdm3` ? And what happens when you stike `ctrl+alt+f1` and `ctrl+alt+f2` ?

Comment: Ctrl+alt+f2 opens another screen (posted in the edit) ctrl+alt+f1 get back to the screen that I'm using. sudo apt list --installed | grep gdm3 returns nothing but the command without "--installed" returns a message that I posted in the edit @GuillaumeF93

Comment: So you don't have gdm3 installed

Comment: So can I install from here? Or I need to reboot and reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think so. try installing gdm from here and you will see if everything is working as you want.

Comment: "*a sudo apt dist-upgrade **without seeing what was gonna be changed***" Looking for the I-have-learned-my-lesson-to-never-do-that.

Comment: Your pictures cut off a lot of text (please in future don't do the screenshot thing. copy and paste the text) but I see xserver-xorg-input-all and other important things getting removed, which sounds alarming.

Answer (score 0):

To give a clean answer:

Re-install gdm:

> sudo apt install gdm3

To get internet access for `apt` use either a Ethernet connection or use a phone with internet connection sharing via USB.